# Jenkins Job - Build If SQL Condition True

Tags: sql, triggers, hudson

We want to setup a hudson job that will execute a query every 10 minutes looking for a date column to equal current date. If this condition is false the job should just loop and run again in 10 minute intervals until the condition is true at which point we want the job to move on to a 2nd step which will execute another sql to update a table. Is it possible to set this up in a single job? I have been searching but have not found an example of this scenario anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.It can be pretty simple actually.

Make a new job in Hudson which automatically runs every 10 minutes.As for the job content,write some shell script to do the sql search. Then if the code returns true, continue with the 2nd step,if not,just end the job.It will be started by Hudson 10 minutes later.